# How to transfer an image using the C++ via ZMQ?

Tags: c++, zeromq

```
#include <zmq.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/dnn.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <cmath>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv2/core/ocl.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <opencv2/core/mat.hpp>
#include <vector>

typedef unsigned char uchar;

using namespace std;

int main() {

  // initialize the zmq context with a single IO thread
    zmq::context_t context{1};

  // Create a subscriber socket
    zmq::socket_t socket{context, zmq::socket_type::sub};

  // Subscribe to the default channel
  //socket.subscribe("");

    socket.set(zmq::sockopt::subscribe, "");

  // Connect to the publisher
  socket.connect("tcp://localhost:4242");


  for(;;) {

    // wait for reply from server
        zmq::message_t reply{};
        //cv::Mat reply;
    int width = 300; // My image width
    int height = 300; // My image height

        socket.recv(reply, zmq::recv_flags::none);
       cv::Mat output = cv::imdecode(reply,1);
       cv::imshow("Output", output);
  }

  // Unreachable, but for good measure
  socket.disconnect("tcp://192.168.0.210:4242");
  return 0;
}
}
```

This is the code I wrote. I am definitely not able to compile since the data type for imdecode does not match. I have seen various C++ subscribers , but I am not able to get the image. This program is basically for live streaming via zmq from the raspi camera module.Each frames are sent from the publisher and the subscriber needs to just show these frames .

Comment: So, you already received an image but need to convert it to something CV can display? What are the types, what is their content? I don't think it matters that ZMQ is involved in your project.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.